# SaltStack schedule loss of data

Tags: scheduler, salt-stack

My scheduler looks like

`get ithrottle stats:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - job_args:
      - get_ithrottle
    - seconds: 300
    - returner: influxdb`

But I see sometimes data is lost. Will adding splay will help.
Whats the main purpose of splay here?

Answer (score 0):

Splay:

`splay
The amount of time in seconds to splay a scheduled job. Can be specified as a single value in seconds or as a dictionary range with 'start' and 'end' values.`

is a random startup delay but I don't know why do you get data lost so I cannot say if splay will help you.

Splay is usually used when you have a lot of minions and you don't want them to run something at the same time which might make the master load go high.

I would suggest you check the logs and see why the events are lost.